# Minecraft /op with a specific level of operating power

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if it is possible to directly OP someone with a specific level. For example something along the lines of /op player permissionLevel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**. There is no way in vanilla Minecraft to give some players different op levels. All ops are defined in the same `ops.txt` file, and the permission level is defined globally in the `server.properties` file.

Comment: The only possible differentiation that ops can possibly have is console access vs not, since console always has full permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in the `ops.json` file:

```
 "uuid": "idk what it is",
    "name": "playername",
    "level": CHANGE THIS TO CHANGE LEVEL,
    "bypassesPlayerLimit": true/false
```